# CypherResults py2neo get node object

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

i need to get the id of a node in neo4j using py2neo. using the following query i am  getting a cypher result object which contains a record object

```
table_query = neo4j.CypherQuery(db, "merge (x: Table{name: 'table_param'}) return x")
```

the contents of the .data method are equal to the following
    [Record(x=Node('host/db/data/node/31'))]

how can i get the node object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CypherQuery gives you a [CypherResults](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cypher/#py2neo.neo4j.CypherResults) object if you `.execute()` it or an [IterableCypherResult](http://book.py2neo.org/en/latest/cypher/#py2neo.neo4j.IterableCypherResults) object if you `.stream()` it.

You can then iterate over the result object:

```
table_query = neo4j.CypherQuery(db, "merge (x: Table{name: 'table_param'}) return x")
results = table_query.execute()

for r in results:
    # get the node you return in your query
    my_node = r[0]
    # get the properties of your node
    props = my_node.get_properties()
```